# Exclude root drive selection from JFileChooser in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a requirement where a user browse through `JFileChooser` and selects a folder.

But while doing this selection the user should not be allowed to select root drive. By "Root Drive" I mean `C:` or `D:` etc. in Windows and `/` in UNIX/Linux.

I think here I can not use filters for `JFileChooser` as its job is to browse through the files and hence it does not make any sense to filter the drive itself.

Please suggest a proper solution which may work on all Windows/Linux file System.

Answer (score 0):

You can `attach event` with it and then in your event code apply filters to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
//This file filter shouldn't be added to the chooser
final FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if(!f.isDirectory())
            return false;
        for(File root : File.listRoots())
            if(f.equals(root))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String getDescription() { return null; }
};
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser() {
    @Override
    public void approveSelection() {
        if(filter.accept(getSelectedFile()))
            super.approveSelection();
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Illegal selection");
    }
};
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```